# Apply Eigenvalues to a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I would like to apply `Eigenvalues[]` to a list of matrices as in the following

```
foo[x_,y_]=x+y;

({{foo[#1, #2], foo[#1, #1]},
 {foo[#1, #1], foo[#1, #2]}}) & @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}

--> {{{3, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 2}, {2, 3}}}

Eigenvalues @@@ %
```

However, I get the error-message "Eigenvalues::matsq: Argument 3 at position 1 is not a non-empty square matrix". What is the problem?

Comment: You need to use `Map`, not `Apply`.  Additional braces are not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Padding additional brackets is not the right way to do it. You should use the right function for the task, which is `Map`:

```
matrices = {{{3, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 2}, {2, 3}}};
Eigenvalues /@ matrices
```

If you're insistent on using `Apply` (why?), then the following ways work:

```
Eigenvalues[{##}] & @@@ matrices
Eigenvalues @@@ List /@ matrices
```

Comment: `EigenValues @@@ {matrices}` does not do the same thing as the others.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks for catching that! Fixed now.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for fixing it. +1

Answer (score 2):

I got it: one has to put additional brackets around the first pure function:

```
{({{foo[#1, #2], foo[#1, #1]},
 {foo[#1, #1], foo[#1, #2]}})} & @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}
```